# Prove of disprove that <U,•> is isomorphic to <R,+>

Tags: abstract-algebra

U is the set of all complex numbers of absolute value 1 and the operation •,+ denotes usual multiplication and addition respectively.

I was trying to show that those aren't isomorphic to each other. So I check some properties of isomorphism, that is commutativeness, identity elt, inverse elt, and idenpotent.

But I can't find difference between those two group.

So I disprove statement following this.

For a in U a•a = -1 has two solutions a = i , -i
But for b in R b+b = -1 has only one solutions . b = - 1/2

Could it be right proof?

Comment: This is exactly the right idea: in more fancy language, $U$ has an element of order 2, while $R$ does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found  two solutions of $a*a=-1$ in $U$, namely $\pm i$. You then tried to find two real numbers $b$ satisfying $b+b=-1$, and found only one. It seems that you suppose that $-1\in U$ would correspond to $-1\in{\mathbb R}$ under a prospective isomorphism, but this need not be the case. Instead say: For any given $c\in{\mathbb R}$ the equation $x+x=c$ has exactly one solution $x\in{\mathbb R}$.

Comment: Sorry but $\pm i$ have order $4$, not $2$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't know that under the supposed isomorphism $-1$ is mapped to $-1$.

Rather, consider that $(\mathbb{R},+)$ has no element with finite order (except for $0$), whereas $-1$ has order $2$ in $(\mathbb{U},\cdot)$.

Said in a different way, no nonzero subgroup of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is finite, whereas $(\mathbb{U},\cdot)$ has a finite subgroup of order $2$.